# clean CSV column value as JSON to C# object

Tags: c#, json, csv

I've got some text written in a CSV column that is supposed to represent a JSON string:

```
{
"text": "foil text1",
"image": "existing_image_uploaded.png",
    "score": false
},

{
"text": "foil text2",
"image": "existing_image_uploaded2.png",
    "score": true
}
```

This CSV text comes out as the following string:

```
 var foils = "{\n    \"text\": \"foil text1\",\n    \"image\": \"existing_image_uploaded.png\",\n        
 \"score\": false\n},\n\n{\n    \"text\": \"foil text2\",\n    \"image\": 
 \"existing_image_uploaded2.png\",\n        \"score\": true\n}"
```

I would like to convert this text to a List of the following class

```
public class FoilJSON{
    public string text {get;set;}
    public string image {get;set;}
    public bool score {get;set;}
}
```

This is the way I would like to convert the JSON to a List of FoilJSON

```
var converted = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<FoilJSON>>(foils);
```

However the string foils is not in a proper JSON format to convert to a base class.
Is there a C# library or method to remove all the CSV garbage within the foils string?

Comment: _"However the string foils is not in a proper JSON format to convert to a base class."_ - what do you mean by that? You aren't using any base-classes and I don't see how mentioning CSV is relevant seeming as you extracted the text fine - so please post more details of how you come into processing invalid JSON...

Comment: Add square brackets around your string (within quotes) to make it a list of objects. Then deserialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var foils = "[{\n    \"text\": \"foil text1\",\n    \"image\": \"existing_image_uploaded.png\",\n        
 \"score\": false\n},\n\n{\n    \"text\": \"foil text2\",\n    \"image\": 
 \"existing_image_uploaded2.png\",\n        \"score\": true\n}]"
```

You have to have square brackets to have a list otherwise you simply have two objects separated by a comma... doesn't really make it a correct json

Answer (score 1):

try this, this code will convert your invalid json string to a json string of JArray of JObjects. After this you can use a serializer to deseialize a json string to  an instance of c#

```
foils = "[" + foils + "]";

List<FoilJSON> converted = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<FoilJSON>>(foils);
```